# Intel Wifi Periodically Drops Many Packets - Becomes Unusable

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on a ThinkPad 420 with an Intel wifi card. My wifi connection will go through periods of dropping many packets to the point where it becomes unusable. The connection never actually drops and the icon shows good signal strength. Turning off wifi and turning it back on again always fixes the problem, but sometimes only for a minute or two until it happens again. Wired connections work reliably.

Things I've tried:

- Changing router WPA settings
- Switching routers
- Adjusting power saving mode
- Switching to wicd
- Setting my iw region
- Turning off IPv6
- Reconfiguring all the network packages from scratch

...And any other proposed fix I can find. [Here is the output of the wireless-info script while the problem is occurring](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkryi3nitw7z94g/wireless-info.txt?dl=0).

It seems as though the problem has been getting worse over the course of the last year. Thank you!

Comment: You're using channel 10, which is kind of an odd channel. Set your router to use channel 1 or 6 or 11 to start, then reconnect, and watch the error count on `iwconfig`. Try all three channels. If you have `Wi-Fi Analyzer` on your smartphone, you can do this a little more scientifically, by looking at the channel usage in your area. You can also turn off bluetooth and see if that helps too. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. The router was set to automatically choose a channel. Wi-Fi Analyzer says that they're pretty evenly saturated in my building, so I set it to channel 1 but it did not solve the problem. :( Any other suggestions, @heynnema? Thank you!

Comment: No, sorry. I don't have any more ideas at this time.

Comment: [Output of `systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwrbwu5fpmh2zvh/systemctl.txt?dl=0).